# Do closed form/exact solutions for this class of ODE exist?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Do solutions or any of the ordinary techniques for ODE solve

$$    F(y,x)y' = A(x) + yB(x)    $$

where $y' = d/dx y(x)$.

As a further restriction you can consider: $F(y,x) = y - G(x)$ where $G,A,B$  are polynomial functions in $x$ alone. I should say that these functions might contain terms of degree zero, i.e. not be homogeneous.

Hence a more correct picture would be:

$$    F(y,x)y' = x-\gamma + y(\beta + \alpha x^2)    $$

where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are real valued parameters.

Answer (score 1):

1. Suppose $F(y,x)$ and $A(x)$ are homogeneous functions of degree $n$, and $B(x)$ is a homogeneous function of degree $n-1$.  Then changing variables $y=xu$ gives an equation of the form $u'(x)=H(u(x))$, to which separation of variables can be applied.

For example,  $F(x,y)=ax^2+bxy+cy^2$ is homogeneous of degree 2.

2. If we know $F(y,x)=y-G(x)$, then it's natural to change variables $z=F=y-G(x)$.  We get $zz'-zG'=A+(z+G)B$, or $zz'=A+BG+(G'+B)z$.  If $B+G'=0$, then this equation is explicitly solvable after letting $u=z^2/2$.
3. $F(y,x)=[A(x)+yB(x)]/G(x,y)$, where $G(x,y)$ is any function such that $y'=G(x,y)$ is solvable.  Either $y$ solves $y'=G$, or $A+By=0$.